# i am creating a project in python it is a game of cards

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

```
class Card:
    
    def _init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
        
        def _str__(self):
            return self.rank+ "of" +self.suit

two_hearts = Card("Hearts", "Two")

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-a9daf7e71915> in <module>
----> 1 two_hearts = Card("Hearts", "Two")

TypeError: Card() takes no arguments
```

#i have added both the code and the error i am getting
the top part is the code and the bottom part is the error.

Comment: You have a typo `__init__` not `_init__`. `_str__` should also be `__str__`

Comment: There's also indentation errors.

Answer (score 1):

It needs an [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__init__#object.__init__) method, you write it as `_init__`.

Answer (score 0):

you need additional underscore in `_init__` also fix indentation of `str` and also additional underscore

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + " of " + self.suit


two_hearts = Card("Hearts", "Two")
print(str(two_hearts))
```